# Predicting percent of male and female party attendees

Tags: probability, estimation, predictive-models

## Problem #1: easy, probably solved

Suppose someone holds a party (A) and invites $n_A$ people. You're not attending a party, but you get full list of guests' identity card and are told that out of $n_A$ people $m_A$ were male (obviously, $n_A-m_A$ were female).

After some time, there's another party (B) coming up. You also get a list of guests' identity cards ($n_B$ people in the list) and this time list includes $k$ people from the previous list, and $n_B - k$ new people, newer encountered before.

**Problem**: Is it possible to predict the number of males and females attending the second party and give some reliability estimates?

I believe that this should be a classic problem - but I haven't seen statistics for a decade and my skills became quite rusty. I've dug up some of my stat books for a while and couldn't find a reference.

My thoughts:

- Edge case 1: if $k=0$, then it shouldn't be possible to predict anything
- Edge case 2: If $k = n_A = n_B$, then it's exactly $m_A$ males and $n_A - m_A$ females, with confidence = 1
- From what we know from the party A, for every guest who attended it, there's a $1/m_A$ probability that this guest's male and $1-1/m_A$ probability that this guest's female.
- It's easy to predict mean value of males for $k$ people, that would be $k/m_A$ and mean value of females - $k-k/m_A$.
- As for new guests, never seen before, it all depends on expected probability distribution. I see 2 viable alternatives:

  - Assuming that there's an even distribution of males/females, $n_B-k$ new guests would be distributed 1:1 male:female, thus yielding mean values of $(n_B-k)/2$ males and $(n_B-k)/2$ females.
  - Assuming the same distribution as it was at the party A, there would be mean value of $(n_B-k)(m_A/n_A)$ males and $(n_B-k)(n_A-m_A)/n_A$ females.
- Summing up, it gives us mean values:

  - Version 1: $(n_B - k)/2 + k/m_A$ males and $(n_B + k)/2 - k/m_A$ females.
  - Version 2: $(n_B-k)(m_A/n_A) + k/m_A$ males and $n_B - (n_B-k)(m_A/n_A) - k/m_A$ females

Is there an error in my thoughts here?

## Problem #2: harder, don't know how to solve

If the solution to problem #1 seems okay, then a harder problem is when we have more than 1 party with known guest IDs and male/female distribution. We have full lists of guest and thus we can calculate any intersections between sets of guests at any parties. Probably, I should somehow adjust first probability estimation for any given guest (i.e. $1/m_a$ male probability) with additional data, but how to do that?

Probably, it's also a classic problem, so if anyway can give me a pointer to the right direction, it would be most appreciated.

Comment: Why not just add up all the other parties and treat them as one single party? Then problem 2 becomes problem 1.

Comment: The problem is that other parties guest lists may intersect with first party. I.e. when the same person attended party A, it has $1/m_A$ probability of being male judging from party A, then it attended party B and so it has $1/m_B$ probability of being male judging only from party B. What's the probability of him being male, judging from results both parties?

Comment: Yes, but if you have IDs, you can eliminate duplicates, right? So, new probability is $\frac{1}{m_{tot}}$ is it not?

Comment: The idea is not to *eliminate* duplicates, but use additional data for further clarification of chances. For example, if a given person was at the party #1 with 10% of males and then the same person was at the party #2 with 100% of males, we should assume that he's surely male. Even if party #2 had, for example, 99% of males, chances that this given person is male are much higher than 10% that we've decided on after party #1.

Comment: Hmmm.  I see. There's probably an analytic solution, although I don't know what it is. You could also simulate it. I think it might depend on size of parties and number of people who were at both, but that's just my intuition.